# How can I insert a script into HTML head dynamically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic

How can I insert a script into HTML head dynamically using JavaScript?

Comment: What server side language do you use?

Comment: no server side language i want to use.

Comment: using javascript at button click i want to insert into head.

Comment: Check this solution: http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = function() {
    callFunctionFromScript();
}
script.src = 'path/to/your-script.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I injected a function on the fly without any source file, etc.

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script').text = 'function LogIt(msg) { console.log(msg);}' );
```

And to inject to body

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script').text = 'function LogIt(msg) { console.log(msg);}' );
```

After executing this, if you try `LogIt('hello');`, you should see 'hello' in the console.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script').setAttribute('src','http://ex.com/javascript.js'));
```

Comment: This should not work since `setAttribute()` does not return the element: "Return Value: No return value" https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp But you can put element in a variable `element`, then call `element.setAttribute(...)` and `appendChild(element)`

Comment: An explanation would be in order.